# Is it possible to create a table using rows from another table as table columns?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

naI'm new to android development. I was wondering if this is possible.

I have this table as tab1

```
____________________________________________
| student ID|  Name   |  Age     | Gender  |
|-----------|---------|----------|---------|
|   11111   | Student1|  11      |    m    |
------------|---------|----------|---------|
|   222222  | Student2|  22      |    f    |
------------|---------|----------|---------|
|   333333  | Student3|  33      |    f    |
------------|---------|----------|---------|
|   444444  | Student4|  44      |    m    |
--------------------------------------------
```

And I want to create a new table. But I want to use the rows from table 1 as columns in this new table.

```
________________________________________________________________
|   QuizID  | Date    |  Items   | Student1| Student2| Student3|
|-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|---------|
|  00000001 |  10-1-14|    10    |    9    |     10  |   6     |
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|---------|
|  00000002 |  10-2-14|    15    |    10   |     9   |   15    |
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|---------|
|  00000003 |  10-3-14|    20    |    20   |    15   |   10    |
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|---------|
|  00000004 |  10-4-14|    10    |    4    |     5   |   10    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Not clear. Your resulting table is not what you describe.  I suggest you fill-in your source table with sample data and then show the expected result.

Comment: It is possible: you can create new tables at any time with the Create Table SQL code; but you should not need to do that unless you have a twisted design. Typically your table will contain at least dozens or hundreds of records, you should not create a table with 100 columns.

Comment: I'll be using my table to store student's scores. The list will probably need 50 columns. Any advice on any alternative that I can do?

Comment: Yes. Use normalized schema. Have multiple tables connected by Primary and Foreign Keys.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Android and/or SQLite. It's basic data modeling.